# A Java bot that uses Skype API

Tags: java, skype

Is there an **up-to-date** Java API for Skype 4.0? I'd need a simple bot that creates a chat and follows discussion.

If there isn't a Java API, what ways are there to send Skype commands in Java?

Also, am I allowed to use public Skype for that, or do I need to have my own Jabber server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Skype4Java](https://developer.skype.com/wiki/Java_API) wrapper for the [Skype API](https://developer.skype.com/Docs/ApiDoc)

Skype itself is a proprietary protocol - it doesnt use Jabber. The only way to interface with skype at present is through a plugin for their client, using the API as mentioned.

I believe the API also works for version 4.